# Add column based on values in other column using query

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table:

```
column
1
2
3
1
7
```

I want to add the other column so that the value next to one is 'primary' and all the others 'non-primary':

```
column   column1
1        primary
2        non-primary
3        non-primary
1        primary
```

I could only thought about using CTE and 'create view' and then alter table and update but I guess there is a simpler way to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for a `case` expression?

```
select column, (case when column = 1 then 'primary' else 'non-primary' end) as column1
from t;
```